# want to start reading a file from a specific point

Tags: java

I have a file that contains log print out and I want to read certain lines and from certain point from the middle to the end of the line and move to the next line that match the criteria.
I want to start reading from RULE EXECUTING to the end of the line and then check the next line of it has RULE EXECUTING if not skip it to the following line if that does have RULE EXECUTING then copy from that point to the end of the line.

```
 FILE SAMPLE

2013-02-14 09:26:20:078 [main] DEBUG sne.ABC.hdhdh.jfjjfj.jkfjfjd.jdsd - RULE EXECUTING --> CMNETSL.hdjjjdlskdnlskd.jgfkdflkdfl_Translation
2013-02-14 09:28:00:312 [main] DEBUG moc.uty.lweifoisd.sfsd.kjfdnkjs.RulesetInvoker  - Rudejgfjkgjf:  After invoking: CMNETSLO
2013-02-14 09:26:20:421 [main] DEBUG sne.ABC.hdhdh.jfjjfj.jkfjfjd.jdsd - RULE EXECUTING --> sne.ABC.hdhdh.jfjjfj.jkfjfjd.jdsd


what I want to get from the line would look like this

RULE EXECUTING --> CMNETSL.hdjjjdlskdnlskd.jgfkdflkdfl_Translation
RULE EXECUTING --> sne.ABC.hdhdh.jfjjfj.jkfjfjd.jdsd
```

Answer (score 0):

So, something like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mylog.log"));

String line;
int idx;
while((line = br.getLine()) != null)
  if((idx = line.indexOf("RULE EXECUTING --> ")) != -1)
    System.out.println(line.substring(idx));
```

I've not tried that in an ide or compiled it, but I think that you probably get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("log.txt")); // read file using scanner line by line

while(s.hasNextLine())
{

    String nextLine = s.nextLine(); 

    if(nextLine.startsWith("RULE EXECUTING")) //check if line starts with the key word
    {
              // do whatever you want to do 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the entire file for that, use a FileReader and read the file line for line, searching for the substring "RULE EXECUTING" in each. If it is found, use the substring method to output or otherwise process the substring. Repeat until the file is done and - most importantly - close the file.

Here is a complete codesample:

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        //open file
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.log"));

        int index;

        //read first line
        String line = reader.readLine();

        //go through the entire file line for line
        while (line != null) {

            //look for substring in line
            index = line.indexOf("RULE EXECUTING");
            if(index >= 0 ) {
                //substring found, write result to stdout
                System.out.println(line.substring(index));
            }

            //read next line
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            //always close file readers!
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your insight and sample code but I have one more question: if I want to get the first "RULE EXECUTING" or how many "RULE EXECUTING" before a line without it and then collect the next set after that line and then compare it. Some thing like this first set of "RULE EXECUTING" compare to second set, 3rd set, 4th set and then move to 2nd set and compare to 3rd and 4th and then compare 3rd and 4th....

Comment: hmm I don't understand your question, do you think you could explain in more detail? Maybe edit or original question or post a new one. I'm sorry about the late response.